# c++ thrift client not working with ssl (SSL_connect hangs)

Tags: c++, ssl, thrift

I wanted to use ssl support provided by thrift in my c++ server and client. My own thrift client was always hanging in SSL_connect after it passes through "transport->open()"
. So I built the official thrift\thrift-0.9.1\test\cpp\src\TestServer.cpp and testclient.cpp for windows. Same thing happened to me here as well.

I really could use any help or pointers.

Update:

I also tried using the latest sources at https://github.com/apache/thrift
Before I was working with 0.9.1

---

Since I saw testserver.cpp was doing the following

```
    sslSocketFactory->loadCertificate("./server-certificate.pem");
    sslSocketFactory->loadPrivateKey("./server-private-key.pem");
    sslSocketFactory->ciphers("ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
```

and the testclient.cpp was doing the following

```
    factory->ciphers("ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");
    factory->loadTrustedCertificates("./trusted-ca-certificate.pem");
    factory->authenticate(true);
```

So I took following steps to build the certs

```
openssl genrsa -out ca-private-key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 3600 -key ca-private-key.pem -out ca-certificate.pem 

openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3600 -nodes -keyout server-private-key.pem -out server-request.pem
openssl rsa -in server-private-key.pem -out server-private-key.pem
openssl x509 -req -in server-request.pem -days 3600 -CA ca-certificate.pem -CAkey ca-private-key.pem -set_serial 01 -out server-certificate.pem
```

Output for different test cases-

---

```
TestServer.exe --ssl
TestClient.exe --host 192.168.0.4 --ssl

I saw TestClient.exe hang on SSL_connect while running       
  testClient.testVoid();
```

During hang server side callstack
[image]

During hang client side callstack. Clearly both sides are stuck reading!
[image]

Wireshark debug trace for the above mentioned client server communication.

[image: Wireshark Trace]

```
Debug output through "openssl s_client" run against thriftserver-

openssl s_client -connect 192.168.0.4:9090 -state -debug
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(00000100)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
write to 0x1e2b5c0 [0x1e2bf50] (321 bytes => 321 (0x141))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 3c 01 00 01-38 03 03 52 dc 25 39 ad   ....<...8..R.%9.
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
```

---

```
TestServer.exe --ssl --server-type nonblocking
TestClient.exe --ssl

I saw TestClient.exe failed on SSL_connect (10054) while running       
  testClient.testVoid();

Server stderr was saying 
Thrift: Sat Jan 18 19:31:21 2014 TNonblockingServer: frame size too large (369295616 > 268435456) 
from client <Host: ::1 Port: 22869>. Remote side not using TFramedTransport?

openssl.exe s_client -connect localhost:9090 -state -debug  
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(0000018C)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
write to 0x6db5c0 [0x6dbf50] (321 bytes => 321 (0x141))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 3c 01 00 01-38 03 03 52 db 4b 8a dd   ....<...8..R.K..
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
read from 0x6db5c0 [0x6e14b0] (7 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFF))
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
write:errno=10054
```

---

```
TestServer.exe --ssl --server-type nonblocking --transport framed
TestClient.exe --ssl --transport framed

Server stderr was saying 
Thrift: Sat Jan 18 19:36:01 2014 TNonblockingServer: frame size too large (36929
5616 > 268435456) from client <Host: ::1 Port: 23087>. Remote side not using TFramedTransport?
```

By stepping through I definitely confirmed that testclient was using framed transport.

Comment: I suggest to ask the question also on the Thrift mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I know what may be going on and might have discovered the bug.

After debugging further I saw that virtual function createSocket is declared with parameter "int"

boost::shared_ptr createSocket(int socket);
https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TSSLServerSocket.h
https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TSSLServerSocket.cpp

However the base class TServerSocket.h declare it as "THRIFT_SOCKET" which on windows is ULONG_PTR

virtual boost::shared_ptr createSocket(THRIFT_SOCKET client);
https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TServerSocket.h

Hence correct createSocket was not being called from the guts.

After making this change I am able to move forward which I confirmed again with openssl s_client -connect localhost:9090 -state -debug

I will send my patch to thrift dev in case they would like to accept it.

Comment: We can tell *after* we reviewed the patch :-)

Comment: JensG- I submitted the pull requests at https://github.com/apache/thrift/pulls (77 & 78). But I have been told by those guys to create jira ticket first. I will have to find time to do all that :)

Comment: Those guys :-) can do the review via GitHub, but they :-) need the JIRA ticket for legal reasons to finally commit it into the ASF codebase. See http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-dev/201310.mbox/%3CCANyrgvc2e_8wzDWoJ=OToO4dEpR9uHipevn2NUh93gFT9RV9Hg@mail.gmail.com%3E for an explanation. Therefore, in most cases, people tend to act more on JIRA tickets.